# check a user_role laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, roles

What would be the best way to add a custom validation of checking if a user has a certain role. using a roles table and role_user pivot table

the roles table has 3 roles

1 user
2 mentor
3 admin

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => [
        'required','string',
        Rule::exists('users')->where(function ($query){
            $query->where('active', true);
            }),
        ], 

        'password' => 'required|string',
       ], $this->validation_errors());

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the middleware documentation: [Laravel - Middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware)

You should create a middleware that checks if the user has the role you want and add it to your route.

Comment: I have middleware to redirect a user depending on the role but I would like to check if they are using the correct login form. Each user has their own section and if a user is trying to login to the wrong one i would like to alert them their account doesn't have the permissions to be there.